# Exportar múltiplos arquivos .csv em R

Tags: r

Estou a tentar a exportação de múltiplos arquivos `.csv` em R através da função `lapply`. Estes arquivos estão dentro de uma lista. Tentei as seguintes configurações:

```
lapply(list,function(x)
write.csv2(list$x,paste0(x),row.names=FALSE))

lapply(seq_along(list),function(x)
write.csv2(list$x,paste0(x),row.names=FALSE))
```

entre outras, as quais retornaram mensagens de erro.

O `dput` (uma lista, na verdade) segue abaixo:

```
lista=structure(list(dados1 = structure(list(aa = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7), bb = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)), .Names = c("aa", "bb"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame"), dados2 = structure(list(cc = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), dd = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)), .Names = c("cc", 
"dd"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("dados1", 
"dados2"))
```

Necessito de uma resposta com `lapply`, pois com `for` eu consigo fazer a exportação. Desta forma, é mais uma curiosidade em saber o por quê de `lapply` não funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o problema é na indexação que você utiliza: `$`. Podemos acessar cada elemento de uma lista com `$` e com `[[]]`:

```
lista$dados1
# aa bb
# 1  1  1
# 2  2  2
# 3  3  3
# 4  4  4
# 5  5  5
# 6  6  6
# 7  7  7

lista[[1]]
# aa bb
# 1  1  1
# 2  2  2
# 3  3  3
# 4  4  4
# 5  5  5
# 6  6  6
# 7  7  7
```

Só que por uma razão desconhecida por mim, quando utilizamos `laapply()` somente `[[]]` funciona. Talvez essa parte do `help(lapply)` possa explicar:

> For historical reasons, the calls created by ‘lapply’ are
>   unevaluated, and code has been written (e.g., ‘bquote’) that
>   relies on this.  This means that the recorded call is always of
>   the form ‘FUN(X[[i]], ...)’, with ‘i’ replaced by the current
>   (integer or double) index.  This is not normally a problem, but it
>   can be if ‘FUN’ uses ‘sys.call’ or ‘match.call’ or if it is a
>   primitive function that makes use of the call.  This means that it
>   is often safer to call primitive functions with a wrapper, so that
>   e.g. ‘lapply(ll, function(x) is.numeric(x))’ is required to ensure
>   that method dispatch for ‘is.numeric’ occurs correctly.

Assim, seu exemplo funcionará se você utilizar `[[]]` ao invés de `$`:

```
lapply(seq_along(lista),function(x) write.csv2(lista[[x]],
                                   file = paste0(names(lista[x]), '.csv'),
                                   row.names = FALSE))
```